# How to reduce an array of object for unique key value pairs using an another array?

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array of object that contains different key value pairs and I'm trying to reduce this array of object using an another array.

I can refer the array that need to be reduced as the "Reducible Array" and the array I'm using to reduce as "Key array".

**Reducible Array:**

```
[
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Avengers",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Captain America",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Justice League",
      "universe": "DC",
      "owned": "Warner Bros"
    }
  }
]
```

**Key Array:**

```
[DC, MARVEL]
```

The reduced array of object I'm expecting after the operation is as follows.

**Expected Result:**

```
[
  {
    "Universe": "MARVEL",
    "OwnedBy": "Walt Disney"
  },
  {
    "Universe": "DC",
    "OwnedBy": "Warner Bros"
  }
]
```

What are all the operations I need to perform to get the expected result?

Comment: You could start with the `filter` method, but since you want to manipulate the items in the result as well, I would probably just go with a manual loop here to begin with. (And then basically create new objects to add to the result array, instead of trying to manipulate the existing ones.) And if you really want to replace `MARVEL` with `Marvel`, but leave `DC` cased as is, then you will need to find some logic to base that case conversion on as well.

Comment: Oh .. The case conversion was a type .. i will Edit it now .. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you naturally felt to use the word `reduce` you must know that javascript offers such a method to reduce arrays:

```js
const keyArray = ['DC', 'MARVEL'];
const array = [
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Avengers",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Captain America",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Justice League",
      "universe": "DC",
      "owned": "Warner Bros"
    }
  }
];

const reducedObject = array.reduce((carry, {movie}) => {
    const key = `${movie.universe}-${movie.owned}`;
    
    if (keyArray.includes(movie.universe) && !carry.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        carry[key] = {universe: movie.universe, owned: movie.owned};
    }
    
    return carry;
}, {});

const reducedArray = Object.values(reducedObject);

console.log(reducedArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant figured out what you need but as for your **expected result array you showed in question** this is my solution

```js
let MovieArr = [
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Avengers",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Captain America",
      "universe": "MARVEL",
      "owned": "Walt Disney"
    }
  },
  {
    "movie": {
      "title": "Justice League",
      "universe": "DC",
      "owned": "Warner Bros"
    }
  }
];

function getUniquie(arr) {
let tempArr = [];
let UniquieObjArr = [];
  arr.forEach((item)=>{
  if(item.movie.universe && tempArr.indexOf(item.movie.universe) === -1){
  tempArr.push(item.movie.universe);
  UniquieObjArr.push({'universe' : item.movie.universe ,'owned' : item.movie.owned})
}
})
return UniquieObjArr;
}
const unquieUniverse = getUniquie(MovieArr);
console.log(unquieUniverse)
```

Comment: But did we use the key array as mentioned in the question ?

Comment: no i didnt that is why i used `tempArr ` variable in function so that i can track if the `universer` is present if its already available then no need to use `tempArr ` you can directly use that in `if` function

Comment: if this answer solved your issue then if accpect my answers thanks